# How to group and display the values in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have created a scope function like this

```
$scope.sample = [
   {'SUPNAME':'AAA','SUPCODE':'22671','SLIPNO':'18384','DESG':'1','iv':'1'},
   {'SUPNAME':'AAA','SUPCODE':'22671','SLIPNO':'18384','DESG':'2','iv':'2'},
   {'SUPNAME':'AAA','SUPCODE':'22671','SLIPNO':'18384','DESG':'3','iv':'3'},
   {'SUPNAME':'BBB','SUPCODE':'24603','SLIPNO':'26714','DESG':'1','iv':'4'},
   {'SUPNAME':'BBB','SUPCODE':'24603','SLIPNO':'26714','DESG':'2','iv':'5'},
   {'SUPNAME':'BBB','SUPCODE':'24603','SLIPNO':'26714','DESG':'3','iv':'6'},
]
```

I have to display by grouping with same SUPNAME,SUPCODE,SLIPNO. For example I have to display it like this.

```
SUPNAME:AAA  SUPCODE=22671
DESG 1  DESG2 DESG 3


SUPNAME:BBB   SUPCODE=24603
DESG 1  DESG2 DESG 3
```

So how can I create ng-repeat for this..Kindly give some solution.

Comment: try reformatting the whole sample data... This may speed the iterations. Otherwise you just loop, compare and paint

Comment: You'll need to group the data first. Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! Also see [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: you could simply filter for SupName or Supcode check this out should explain everything http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/common-user-interface-patterns/filtering-and-sorting-a-list.html

Comment: Ok first I will group the data and try it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i tried to create a Codepen for your case

[grouped Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqapzP)

```
<table  class="table table-striped">
<tr><td>{{data1}}</td><td>{{data2}}</td></tr>
<tr ng-repeat="item in filteredsample = (sample | filter:{ SUPNAME: 'AAA'})">
</tr>
  <ul ng-repeat="thing in filteredsample">
<li style = "float:left; margin:20px">DESG VALUE {{$index}} = {{thing.DESG}}</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps