# Group By - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following JSON format, and I am looking to combine the "Virtual" and "Physical" objects into one by grouping by cluster and idc

```
[
{
    "_id": {
        "cluster": 1,
        "idc": "LH8",
        "type": "Virtual"
    },
    "SumCores": 112,
    "SumMemory": 384
},
{
    "_id": {
        "cluster": 1,
        "idc": "LH8",
        "type": "Physical"
    },
    "SumCores": 192,
    "SumMemory": 768
},
{
    "_id": {
        "cluster": 2,
        "idc": "LH8",
        "type": "Virtual"
    },
    "SumCores": 232,
    "SumMemory": 469
},
{
    "_id": {
        "cluster": 2,
        "idc": "LH8",
        "type": "Virtual"
    },
    "SumCores": 256,
    "SumMemory": 1024
}
```

Currently I have all of the output to screen using ng-repeat:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in servers | orderBy:['idc','cluster'] "><p>IDC:{{item._id.idc}} - Cluster: {{item._id.cluster}} - Type: {{item._id.type}} - Sum Cores: {{ item.SumCores }} </p></div>
```

Which produces something similar to:

```
IDC: LH8 - Cluster: 1 - Type: Virtual - Sum Cores: 192
IDC: LH8 - Cluster: 1 - Type: Physical -Sum Cores: 112
IDC: LH8 - Cluster: 2 - Type: Virtual - Sum Cores: 256
IDC: LH8 - Cluster: 2 - Type: Physical -Sum Cores: 232
```

Ideally I want to group this into a table with this as the ideal format:

```
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
| Cluster |         LH5        |         LH8        |
+---------+--------------------+--------------------+
|         | Physical | Virtual | Physical | Virtual |
+---------------------------------------------------+
|       1 |   Value  |  Value  |  Value   |  Value  |
|       2 |   Value  |  Value  |  Value   |  Value  |
|       3 |   Value  |  Value  |  Value   |  Value  |
|       4 |   Value  |  Value  |  Value   |  Value  |
+---------+----------+---------+----------+---------+
```

Obviously there is a lot more data than in my sample and value would represent the SumCores.

I also have access to the controller if you think the change would be  better made in there:

```
Machine.aggregate(  [ { $match : {  $and: [  {"idc": req.query.idc }, {"customer":req.query.customer} ] } } ,{"$group":{_id: {"cluster":"$cluster","idc":"$idc","type":"$type"},"SumCores":{"$sum":"$cores"},"SumMemory": { "$sum":"$memory" }}}, { $sort : { idc : -1, cluster: 1 } } ]).exec(function(err, agg) {

res.json(agg);

});
```

**Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8n227L2o/**

Comment: a plunk/fiddle would be very helpful

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8n227L2o/

Comment: @Jax - added fiddle for you :)

Comment: i did a codepen a while ago where i showed how to group things check it out here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31398614/how-to-group-and-display-the-values-in-angular-js/31399083#31399083

Comment: @stackg91 - thanks but I'm not entirely sure how to implement this in my situation

Answer (score 1):

I've forked your Fiddle, and now I've used Underscore.js to group and filter your data according to your example table.

http://jsfiddle.net/pdc5rvyo/1/

It is quite basic, and uses nested tables. You should be able to customize it by allowing uses to change the order of the lists for example.

Code example:

```
    var lhSortedList = _.groupBy(servers, function(item) {
        return item._id.idc;
    });
    $scope.lh8Virtual = _.filter(lhSortedList['LH8'], function(item) {
        return item._id.type === 'Virtual';   
    });
```

Here is an overview of how to do what you want dynamically:

```
    var lhList = ['LH5', 'LH8']; // sourced from server ?


    var lhSortedList = _.groupBy(servers, function(item) {
        return item._id.idc;
    });

    $scope.lhData = {};

    lhList.forEach(function(lhName) {
        $scope.lhData[lhName + 'Virtual'] = _.filter(lhSortedList[lhName], function(item) {
            return item._id.type === 'Virtual';   
        });
        $scope.lhData[lhName + 'Physical'] = _.filter(lhSortedList[lhName], function(item) {
            return item._id.type === 'Physical';   
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, although the "idc" is dynamic - and shouldn't be hard coded

Comment: Could the solution work with everything being dynamic. The type: Physical and Virtual are the only fixed values.

Comment: Alternatively, you could maintain a separate list of IDC names, and iterate over them...

Comment: Could you please show me an example of how to make it dynamic? I've never really used angular or underscore before so I'm fairly new to the language

Comment: I've added an overview of how to do it dynamically here - I don't have time to pursue it now. Read up on the topics required and consider using a simplified table structure to start with...